# GitHub push fails - Rejected - failed to push refs to github

Tags: git, github

So, I've a local project folder where I initiated a github version control. I created a repo for the same on GitHub and pushed all my files onto it. Everything was working just fine until I noticed that github was not showing anything in my contributions.

On investigation, I found that It was because the default branch was "main". I went into the project settings on GitHub and changed the default branch to "Master". As soon as I did that, all my recent commits started showing up in the contributions section of my profile.

Though It solved one problem, It lead to another big problem. Now, I cannot push anything from my local repository to the one located remotely. Whenever I try to do that, It says:

```
To github.com:divyamdhadwal.........
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:divyamdhadwal......'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Now I tried using git pull but even If i do that, I'm unable to push my local data to my remote github repo after doing it.

I've basic knowledge about github but at this point I simply do not know how i can resolve this issue. I want everything to be in sync again and that I'm able to push my changes from local to remote as I used to do before but keeping the "master" as the default branch on remote (which I've already done using settings)

Kindly help.

Comment: You should `git pull` before you push

Comment: Already done..Still not working. Git pull succeeds but I can still not push after that.

Comment: Please add the output of the subsequent pull and push.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set upsteam to the correct branch on the local repository.
Since you pushed to master, it will keep pushing to that. To change this, try using `--set-upstream-to` flag on push.

> If you already have a local branch and want to set it to a remote
> branch you just pulled down, or want to change the upstream branch
> you’re tracking, you can use the `-u` or `--set-upstream-to` option to
> git branch to explicitly set it at any time.
>
> `$ git branch -u origin/serverfix` Branch serverfix set up to track
> remote branch serverfix from origin.

from [Git's section about tracking branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches). You can check on your software's manual by using `git push --help` or `man git-push` for more details.

So the command you're looking for is `git push -u origin/main`, it will set the upstream and push in one go.

On an unrelated note, please differentiate Git from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would to thank you all who helped me with this query. This is what I did to resolve this issue:

```
 1. Ran git pull origin master
 2. Removed all the merge conflicts manually.
 3. Ran git add .
 4. Did git commit
 5. Pushed my code again.
```

It worked this time..I thought git would merge the conflicts automatically (keeping the most recent commits and discarding the previous ones), though it does not happen. I went to each file and chose which changes i want to keep/discard.

This is now resolved as git status now shows that my local git repo is in sync with origin/master. Cheers!